# SwiftUI: How to convert an Image to jpeg data?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In UIImage, there is the jpegData() method which turns the image into an NSData object of jpeg data.

What would the analogue be for the Image class?

Comment: Sorry but your question is not clear can you please provide more info or example code of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to turn an Image into an NSData object. I was wondering if there was a way to do this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The SwiftUI `Image` is analog of `UIImageView`, not `UIImage`. So if you need to operate with image model, you have to store it explicitly as `UIImage` and operate with it, providing into view as in below example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
   let imageModel: UIImage        // << model

   var body: some View {
      Image(uiImage: imageModel)  // << view
        .onTapGesture {
            // work with model

            let data = self.imageModel.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
            // .. do something with data
        }
   }
}
```